# "tezbridge.request" forge operation failed

Tags: taquito

After multiple failed attempts with `tezos.contract.at(addr).methods.entrypoint(args).send(amount)`, see [Revealed public keys but failed to transfer on GRANADANET](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/revealed-public-keys-but-failed-to-transfer-on-granadanet), I turned to the API `tezbridge.request`.  But still I cannot come over the problem to inject operations in the blockchain.  It kept displaying a warning "forge operation failed" in the tezbridge window.
Did anyone happen to encounter similar issues? Or who knows any platform can let me do some test to debug it with code snippets?  Many thanks.

```
const bet = async (stake_amount,bool_bet) => {
  tezbridge.request({
    method: 'inject_operations',
    operations: [
      {
        kind: 'transaction',
      //tried inserting other parameters like storage_limit, gas_limit, fee, etc.
        amount: stake_amount,
        destination: KT1xxxx,
        parameters: {
          entrypoint: "bet",
          value: bool_bet     //have modified it with many different variations
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by checking up the json, https://rpc.tzkt.io/granadanet/chains/main/blocks/541783/operations/3.  This can be found via json tab on better call dev.

```
const bet = async (stake_amount,bool_bet) => {
   var num_stake_amount = stake_amount*1000000;
   var str_stake_amount = num_stake_amount.toString();
   tezbridge.request({
     method: 'inject_operations',
     operations: [
       {
        "kind": "transaction",
        "source": userAddress,
        "amount": str_stake_amount,
        "destination": ledgerInstance.address,
        "parameters":
        {
          "entrypoint":"bet",
          "value":
          {
            "prim":bool_bet
          }
        }
       }
     ]
   })
   .then(result => alert(JSON.stringify(result)))
   .catch(error => alert(error.toString()))
};
```